# storing sheet data in temp memory for using that for comparing 2 excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code to compare data from 2 sheets, so i have created the vba code but it is slow so i though to store sheet data in temp memory some how and instead switching sheets between it should use from temp memory.

My code-

```
For i = 2 To F1_iRowMax
    Dim RV As Long
    RV = 0

    '   On Error Resume Next
    'RV = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(i, 16384).Value, F2_Workbook.Sheets(ShName2).Range("XFD1:XFD1048576"), 0)
    RV = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(i, 16384).Value, KeyRange, 0)

    On Error Resume Next
    If Not IsError(RV) Then

    Else

    End If

    Counter = 0
    Counter = Counter + 1

    pctdone = Counter / F1_iRowMax

    With ufProgress
        .LabelCaption.Caption = "Comparing Part-1 " & i & " of " & F1_iRowMax
        .LabelProgress.Width = pctdone * (.FrameProgress.Width - 10)
    End With

    If RV <> 0 Then
        ''''F1 VS F2
        ' ColumnNumber = iCol_Max
        'ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, ColumnNumber).Address, "$")(1)

        For iCol = 1 To iCol_Max
            F1_Data = F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(i, iCol)
            F2_Data = F2_Workbook.Sheets(ShName2).Cells(RV, iCol)

            'If i = 39100 Then Stop  '''for debug

            If F1_Data <> F2_Data Then
                '
                sIdx = sIdx + 1
                '   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 1) = F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(iRow, iCol).Address
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 3) = F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(Header, iCol).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 1) = F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(i, 16384).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 2) = F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(i, 1).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 4) = F1_Data
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 5) = F2_Data
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 6) = "Data Mismatch"
                'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 3).Select
            End If
        Next iCol
    Else
        sIdx = sIdx + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 1) = F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(i, 16384).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 2) = F1_Workbook.Sheets(ShName).Cells(i, 1).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 4) = "Record Exist"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 6) = "No Record Found"
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(sIdx, 3).Select
    End If   
Next i
```

I want to compare 40k rows between 2 sheets.

Comment: Checking the sheets/cells directly is extremely slow. Push the values of the ranges in to a variable and then just do all the the checks just in vba

Comment: For that many rows, you really want to be using a Scripting Dictionary Object. Search this site for VBA Dictionary, or check out the excellent article at https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/3391/Using-the-Dictionary-Class-in-VBA.html